# How do you show show a dynamic picture with values from a specific time in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with data for when the doors of a certain house open/close. I would like to be able to create a graphic that would display the state of all the doors at a single time. This time will be chosen by the user with a slicer or something similar.

The end result I am looking for is for the user to be able to move the slicer to see how the doors open and close throughout the day. Green= open, red=close.

The data look like this...

[image: data Screenshot]

If the user chooses a time of 1151 then door1 will appear closed on the graphic and door2 will appear open. I also have a lot of houses with identical layouts and would like the user to be able to choose which house to display.

So far I have tried to use synoptic panel but I am unable to get it to work correctly. It attempts to aggregate the data and does not allow the filtering that I require.

Do I need to use a different tool for this or create a custom visualization?

Comment: Try posting your data sample as text instead of image - it makes it easier to test a solution

Comment: The data that i put in the question was just an example of the way it is structured. there is a column for which house, a column for the door, a column for the type and a column for the state of the door (open/closed).